# How can I export variable groups from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I need to export variable groups from one azure devops to another azure devops project. How can I do this?

Comment: What are options you've looked at so far?

Answer (score 0):

The UI of Azure DevOps doesn't provide such a functionality. This [blog](https://medium.com/objectsharp/how-to-clone-variable-group-with-secrets-75123cbbfe58) explains how to do it using Azure CLI and the Azure DevOps extension for Azure CLI. If you're new to the (Azure DevOps extension for) Azure CLI, then please read my [blog](https://veegens.wordpress.com/2019/09/06/controlling-azure-devops-from-powershell/) to learn how set it up.